# Pass array into COM method call in PowerBuilder

Tags: com, powerbuilder, ole

I want to call a COM object method which takes an argument that is an array from PowerBuilder. The method works fine from other OLE automation controllers (VB6, VBScript, VBA, Delphi, PHP, to name just some of them), and in IDL, it looks like this:

```
    void MyMethod([in, out] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT)* argumentsArray);
```

So far I have not succeeded calling this method from PowerBuilder. I always get runtime error similar to "Invalid parameter type calling external object function MyMethod at line XX in XXXXXX". As far as I can tell, this error is generated by PowerBuilder before my method gets called, i.e. it is not a kind of transformed HRESULT from the method itself, and the method does not get called at all.

I have no problems calling other methods of the same COM object from PowerBuilder - those that do not use arrays as arguments.

Examples of PowerBuilder code that I have tried and does *not* work are:

```
Any Arguments[]
Arguments[1] = MyArgument
MyObject.MyMethod(Arguments)
```

Or

```
OLEObject Arguments[]
Arguments[1] = MyArgument
MyObject.MyMethod(Arguments)
```

Or

```
OLEObject Arguments[0 to 0]
Arguments[0] = MyArgument
MyObject.MyMethod(Arguments)
```

Or

```
OLEObject Arguments[0 to 0]
Arguments[0] = MyArgument
MyObject.MyMethod(REF Arguments)
```

I have searched StackOverflow and the Web, and found only answers to the opposite problem - how to pass the arrays that are results of COM methods back to the PowerBuilder.

How to pass the array then?

Comment: Is `Arguments` a PowerBuilder array of OleObjects or are they PB types? Or is the array an OleObject _itself_?  Also, what PowerBuilder version are you working with?

Comment: "Arguments" is an array of OLEObject-s: it's already declared that way as you can see, and "MyArgument" in my examples is an OLEObject. I am using PowerBuilder 2017 R3.

Comment: I'm reaching way back, but I *think* I had a similar problem years ago with PB9. Ended up having to create a new method on the `OLEObject` that modified/worked-with the array (add/remove/get, i.e.:  `MyObject.AddToArray(MyArgument)`, `MyObject.GetFromArray(0)`), then bypass having it as an argument altogether and just letting the COM object's "processing" method work with it internally...  This approach has been carried through our PB migrations through the years - we're on 12.6 now - and still does the trick. Unfortunately I never revisited it, nor know if PB 2017 requires something different

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know I can work around it by redesigning the interface in various ways. But since it is only PowerBuilder that I can not get to work (the component works and has to work from many other tools), I will only do that as a last resort. So my question was really about whether it is directly doable in PowerBuilder (and how), without changing the COM object.